# Qt - Transform cv::Mat to QImage in worker thread crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv, qimage

## Introduction

What i want is really simple: I want to start the process of reading a binary file via a button in a main ui thread, let a seperate thread handle the processing including transformation into `QImage` and return this image back to the main ui thread where it should shown in a label.

Therefore i use Qt's signal/slot mechanism and its thread functionality.

I allready have a single thread working solution, but when using the threading attempt it crashes on totally arbitrary steps which i don't understand because the whole process is totally encapsulated and not time critical...

---

## Working single-threading solution:

`TragVisMain` is a `QMainWindow`:

```
class TragVisMain : public QMainWindow
```

Pushing the button `readBinSingle` starts the process:

```
void TragVisMain::on_readBinSingle_clicked()
{
    // Open binary file
        FILE *imageBinFile = nullptr;
        imageBinFile = fopen("imageFile.bin", "rb");
        if(imageBinFile == NULL) {
            return;
        }
    
    // Get binary file size
        fseek(imageBinFile, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
        size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(ftell(imageBinFile)); // get current file pointer
        fseek(imageBinFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read binary file
        void *imageData = malloc(size);
        fread(imageData, 1, size, imageBinFile);
    
    // Create cv::Mat
        cv::Mat openCvImage(1024, 1280, CV_16UC1, imageData);
        openCvImage.convertTo(openCvImage, CV_8UC1, 0.04); // Convert to 8 Bit greyscale

    // Transform to QImage
        QImage qImage(
            openCvImage.data,
            1280,
            1024,
            QImage::Format_Grayscale8
        );

    // Show image in label, 'imageLabel' is class member
        imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImage));
        imageLabel.show();
}
```

This works like a charm, but of course the ui is blocked.

---

## Not working multi-threading solution

As you will see the code is basically the same as above just moving to another class `DoCameraStuff`. So here is are the main components for this purpose in the `TragVisMain` header file:

```
namespace Ui {
    class TragVisMain;
}

class TragVisMain : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit TragVisMain(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~TragVisMain();

    private:
        Ui::TragVisMain *ui;
        DoCameraStuff dcs;
        QLabel imageLabel;
        QThread workerThread;

    public slots:
        void setImage(const QImage &img); // Called after image processing
        // I have also tried normal parameter 'setImage(QImage img)', non-const referenc 'setImage(const QImage &img)' and pointer 'setImage(QImage *img)'

    private slots:
        void on_readBin_clicked(); // Emits 'loadBinaryImage'
        // void on_readBinSingle_clicked();

    signals:
        void loadBinaryImage(); // Starts image processing
};
```

`DoCameraStuff` is just a `QObject`:

```
class DoCameraStuff : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit DoCameraStuff(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    public slots:
        void readBinaryAndShowBinPic();

    signals:
        void showQImage(const QImage &image);

};
```

Moving `dcs` to the `workerThread` and `connect`ing signals and slots happens in the constructor of `TragVisMain`:

```
TragVisMain::TragVisMain(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TragVisMain),
    dcs()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    dcs.moveToThread(&workerThread);

    // Object should be deletable after the thread finished!
    connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, &dcs, &QObject::deleteLater);

    // For starting the image processing
    connect(this, &TragVisMain::loadBinaryImage, &dcs, &DoCameraStuff::readBinaryAndShowBinPic);

    // Showing QImage after image processing is done
    connect(&dcs, &DoCameraStuff::showQImage, this, &TragVisMain::setImage);

    // Start workerThread
    workerThread.start();
}
```

Starting the image processing happens through pressing the `readBinSingle` button:

```
void TragVisMain::on_readBin_clicked()
{
    emit loadBinaryImage(); // slot: readBinaryAndShowBinPic
}
```

The process happens in `DoCameraStuff::readBinaryAndShowBinPic`:

```
void DoCameraStuff::readBinaryAndShowBinPic() {
    // Exact same code from single thread solution:
        // Open binary file
            FILE *imageBinFile = nullptr;
            imageBinFile = fopen("imageFile.bin", "rb");
            if(imageBinFile == NULL) {
                return;
            }

        // Get binary file size
            fseek(imageBinFile, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
            size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(ftell(imageBinFile)); // get current file pointer
            fseek(imageBinFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

        // Read binary file
            void *imageData = malloc(size);
            fread(imageData, 1, size, imageBinFile);

        // Create cv::Mat
            cv::Mat openCvImage(1024, 1280, CV_16UC1, imageData);
            openCvImage.convertTo(openCvImage, CV_8UC1, 0.04); // Convert to 8 Bit greyscale

        // Transform to QImage
            QImage qImage(
                openCvImage.data,
                1280,
                1024,
                QImage::Format_Grayscale8
            );

    // Send qImage to 'TragVisMain'
    emit showQImage(qImage);
}
```

Showing the image in `TragVisMain::setImage`:

```
void TragVisMain::setImage(const QImage &img)
{
    imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    imageLabel.show();
}
```

---

## Problem

Well the multi-threading attempt just crashed the whole Application without any message during different steps. But honestly i don't have any idea. For me the `DoCameraStuff` class is a [standard worker class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) doing time-independent stuff in a member function without any critical relations.

I also checked if some of the used function inside `DoCameraStuff::readBinaryAndShowBinPic` are not thread-safe but I couldn't find any problems regarding `<cstdio>`, `cv::Mat` and `QImage` in equivalent conditions.

So:

1. Why does the multi-threading attempt crash?
2. What changes need to be applied, so that the process in the thread does not crash?

I allways appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't use `void setImage(QImage *img);`, instead use `void setImage(const QImage & img);`

Comment: I will change it, problem stays... _I have also tried normal parameter 'setImage(QImage img)' and reference 'setImage(QImage &img)'_

Comment: `QImage &img` is different to `const QImage &img`

Comment: @eyllanesc That's right... I'll try

Comment: @eyllanesc It still crashes, so that is not the problem in this case, i'll update the question.

Comment: It may not be the solution, but you must correct it.

Comment: do the following in a thread: ui->logOutput->appendPlainText(...) is not correct, you should not update the GUI from another thread, you must use the signals to send the log.

Comment: @eyllanesc Was a copy error, in the implementation it's just a return, thanks, sry

Comment: Take your time and delete all the *copy error*, nobody rushes you to post a question. On the other hand, have you used a debugger to see where the problem is? :)

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes i did, The function `DoCameraStuff::readBinaryAndShowBinPic` does run till the end `emit showQImage(qImage);`, then i enter some Qt code and finally end in the Dissambler. The label opens and shows cryptic a pattern, so the image is not shown properly. Please be aware that this behavior is owed by debugging the code slowly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have a chance of working, since the `QImage` wraps transient data that then is deallocated by `cvMat`. At the minimum you should emit the copy of the image (literally `qImage.copy()`. Ideally, you'd wrap the `cvMat` lifetime management in `QImage`'s deleter, so that the copy is not necessary, and the matrix gets destroyed along with the image that wraps it. Since format conversions are usually needed between `cv::Mat` and `QImage`, it's probably best to perform the conversion between the source `cv::Mat` and another `cv::Mat` that wraps the `QImage`-owned memory. That solution avoids memory reallocations, since the `QImage` can be retained in the class performing the conversion. It is then also comaptible with Qt 4, where `QImage` doesn't support deleters.

See [this answer for a complete example of an OpenCV video capture Qt-based widget viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253353/1329652), and [this answer for a complete example of multi-format conversion from `cv::Mat` to `QImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872664/1329652).